# Creating Custom TPanel in run Time Error Delphi

Tags: delphi-7

I have created a instance of 'TPanel' derived class with some code to modify its borders like the next :

```
type
TMyCustuomPanel=class(TPanel)
  private
    procedure SetBounds(Aleft, Atop, Awidth, Aheight:Integer);override;
end;
...

procedure TMyCustuomPanel.SetBounds(Aleft, Atop, Awidth, Aheight: Integer);
var
  Hr:HRGN;
begin
  inherited;
  Hr := CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, ClientWidth, ClientHeight, 20, 20);  // <= Error occurs here
  SetWindowRgn(Handle,Hr,true) ;
end;
```

And then I tried to create it like the next:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Frm:TMyCustuomPanel;
begin
  frm:=TMyCustuomPanel.Create(self);
  Frm.Parent:=Self;
  Frm.Name:='Frm01';
  Frm.Width:=200;
  Frm.Height:=250;
  Frm.Color:=clRed;
end;
```

But I get the Error *'Control '' has no parent window'...*.

Thanks for help.

Delphi 7 Win 7

Comment: Client coordinates requires the window for the control to be created, which requires a parent window for a child window, which is not yet set. You can insert `if not HandleAllocated then Exit` after the `inherited` call, before setting the region.

Comment: Removed extra tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

- The call of `CreateRoundRectRgn` needs to have a handle to work (Actually it is ClientWidth and CLientHeight that need the handle). You can just bypass the call if `SetBounds` is called before a handle has been allocated.
- According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createroundrectrgn), a region created by `CreateRoundRectRgn` needs to be deleted when no longer needed.

Here is the code fixed:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TMyCustuomPanel=class(TPanel)
  private
    FHr : HRGN;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure SetBounds(Aleft,Atop,Awidth,Aheight:Integer); override;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TMyCustuomPanel }

destructor TMyCustuomPanel.Destroy;
begin
  if FHr <> 0 then begin
    DeleteObject(FHr);
    FHr := 0;
  end;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyCustuomPanel.SetBounds(Aleft, Atop, Awidth, Aheight: Integer);
begin
  inherited;
  if HandleAllocated then begin
    if FHr <> 0 then
      DeleteObject(FHr);
    FHr := CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, ClientWidth, ClientHeight, 20, 20);
    SetWindowRgn(Handle, FHr, TRUE);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Frm:TMyCustuomPanel;
begin
  frm                  := TMyCustuomPanel.Create(Self);
  Frm.Parent           := Self;
  Frm.Name             := 'Frm01';
  Frm.Width            := 200;
  Frm.Height           := 250;
  Frm.ParentColor      := FALSE;   // Remove for old Delphi version
  Frm.ParentBackground := FALSE;   // Remove for old Delphi version
  Frm.Color            := clRed;
end;

end.
```

Note: I have tested with D10.4.2 because I have no more Delphi 7 to test with. Probably ParentColor and ParentBackground properties didn't existed yet. Just remove the affected lines if the compiler complains.

Comment: "*`CreateRoundRectRgn` needs to have a handle to work*" - no, it doesn't.  It is `SetWindowRgn()` that does. Two different things. Regions can be used for more than just windows. "*A region created by `CreateRoundRectRgn` needs to be deleted when no longer needed*" - `SetWindowRgn()` takes ownership of the region and will handle that, do not destroy the region manually if `SetWindowRgn()` is successful.